# What's wrong that I get the message [Error] invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int, int, int)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c

What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void x_ispositive(int x) /*check if the number is positive*/
{
   if (x>0)
      printf("It's positive");
   else 
      if(x<0)
         printf("It's negative");
}

void x_isnull(int x) /*check if the number is equal zero*/
{
   if(x==0)
       puts("It's null");
   else
       puts("Equação inexistente...");
}

int delta(int a, int b, int c) /*calculates delta*/
{
   int dt;

   dt = pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);

   return dt;
}

int main()
{
   int a, b, c, num;

   puts("Enter the terms of a quadratic equation.");
   scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

   x_isnull(a);
   delta(a,b,c);
   num = delta;
   x_ispositive(num);

}
```

The error is at line 40 (`num = delta;`):

```
 [Error] invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int, int, int)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `num = delta;` That should be the line, which you haven't indicated. Now think about what it's doing.

Comment: `delta(a,b,c);
   num = delta;` --> `num = delta(a,b,c);`

Comment: You are assigning a function to an integer ...

Comment: Aside: what will `x_ispositive` do when `x == 0`? "Not all control paths return a value."

Answer (score 0):

`num = delta;` attempts to assign a function named `delta` to a function pointer named `num`. This of course doesn't work as `num` is an `int`, not a function pointer. If you wanted this assignment to work, you would declare `num` as `int (*num)(int, int, int)`, however what i believe you meant to do is assign the value of `delta(a,b,c)` to num, as it returns an `int` value. You're almost there, you just need to change these lines:

```
delta(a,b,c);
num = delta;
```

to:

```
num = delta(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers